What is the disagreement between Rebbi Shimon and Rebbi Yehudah regarding muktzah on shabbos vs yomtov?
What is the disagreement between Rebbi Shimon and Rebbi Yehudah regarding Muktzah on Shabbos versus Yom Tov? Additionally, where in the Gemara can I find this?

The disagreement between Rabbi Shimon and Rabbi Yehuda regarding muktzeh is wide ranging and not only about Shabbat versus Yom Tov.
See e.g. Shabbat 45 as explained further here https://www.myjewishlearning.com/article/shabbat-45/
"Today we encounter a debate between Rabbi Shimon and Rabbi Yehuda over the extent of the muktzeh prohibition. Rabbi Yehuda holds by a rather robust definition of the prohibition, while Rabbi Shimon holds that the prohibition does not exist at all — or, perhaps, as we learn later in the page, he has a much more narrow definition of it."
The dispute between the two rabbis comes up in many other places in the gemara where muktzeh is discussed.

@Dude If you are happy with either answer given, please accept it. Otherwise please suggest what you would like to be improved

This is a wide-ranging dispute throughout Shas, where R Yehuda believes "there is muktzeh" and R Shimon believes "there is no muktzeh". These are shorthands, as in reality, R Shimon agrees there is muktzeh but in a more restricted way than R Yehuda. It comes back repeatedly in masechet Shabbat and Beitzah.
This excellent summary describes the six types of muktzeh in dispute between R Yehuda and R Shimon and the five where they agree. It also brings specific sources and references to the relevant gemarot.
This is further complicated by the fact that halacha treats muktzeh more stringently on Yom Tov than on Shabbat, so while the halacha is normally according to R Shimon on Shabbat, according to many it is like R Yehuda with regard to Muktzah on Yom Tov, because on Yom Tov some melachot are permitted, and thus the day needs additional rabbinical safeguards to strengthen the observance of Yom Tov.
